# Write a function, min() that takes an array of numbers and returns the smallest number using Javascript

Tags: javascript

[min](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/receptive-xylophone?path=index.html:69:0)

```js
 <p id="q3">
    junj
    </p>
 <script>
     var minnum

     function min(num1,num2,num3)
      { if (num1<num2)
          {if (num1<num3)
             {minnum=num1}
           else {minnum=num3}
          }
        else if (num1>num2)
          { if (num2>num3)
               {minnum=num3}
           else {minnum=num2}
          }
        else if (num1=num2)
            { if(num1<num3)
              {minnum=num1}
             else {minnum=num3}
            }

       return minnum;



      }
    document.getElementById("q3").innerHTML = min(1,1,0) 
   ;
    </script>
```

This is the updated version of my question. Please do comment if it is sufficient to answer the question.Thanks again. Can't appreciate more.

Comment: there may be a language problem ... largest is maximum, not minimum

Comment: also ... `==` tests for equality, `=` is what you wantt to do to assign to a vairable

Comment: What if `num1 == num2`?

Comment: So I should use minnum=num1?

Comment: you can use Math.max(1,2,3) to get largest number

Comment: that's the problem, my teacher doesn't allow this. He wants to practice our basics.

Comment: What's the downvote for? Is it because I am editing too frequently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One equals (`=`) is for assignment, two equals (`==`) is for comparison. You have two equals in your assignments like  `minnum == num1`, and so your function returns `undefined`. Correcting this outputs the smallest number, as expected:

```js
var minnum;

function min(num1, num2, num3) {
  if (num1 < num2) {
    if (num1 < num3) {
      minnum = num1;
    } else {
      minnum = num3;
    }
  } else if (num1 > num2) {
    if (num2 > num3) {
      minnum = num3;
    } else {
      minnum = num2;
    }
  }
  return minnum;
}

console.log(min(1, 2, 3));
```

However, it's also worth mentioning that the *largest* is 3, which is *not* the same as the minimum. This would be the *maximum* value, and to obtain this, simply invert all of the comparison signs:

```js
var minnum;

function min(num1, num2, num3) {
  if (num1 > num2) {
    if (num1 > num3) {
      minnum = num1;
    } else {
      minnum = num3;
    }
  } else if (num1 < num2) {
    if (num2 < num3) {
      minnum = num3;
    } else {
      minnum = num2;
    }
  }
  return minnum;
}

console.log(min(1, 2, 3));
```

Note that it may also be worth changing the function name to something like `max()` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you. That solved my previous question. Now I am working on the equal condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want minimum number from array which has no fixed length
try this

```
     function min(numarray)
      { 
      numarray.sort(function(a, b){return a-b}); //sort the array in 
      return numarray[0]; //the first number in your array is minimum number
      }
      var numberArray=[3,1,2,7];
      console.log(min(numberArray))
    //document.getElementById("q3").innerHTML = min(numberArray);
```

Jsfiddle Link
https://jsfiddle.net/pg4abkx7/